# Error bound by the Simpson's rule

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

My lecture notes have a little exercise. Two functions are given: $$ f(x) = \cos(x) \ \text{and} \ g(x)=\sqrt{x+1} $$

And we're asked about the error bound of the Simpson's rule to estimate the integral on $[0,1]$. The formula for that is $$|I(f)-Q(f)|\leq\frac{\| f^{(4)} \|_\infty}{90}\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^5$$

My calculations:

$$|I(f)-Q(f)|\leq\frac{1}{90}\left(\frac{1-0}{2}\right)^5$$
$$|I(g)-Q(g)|\leq\frac{15/16}{90}\left(\frac{1-0}{2}\right)^5$$

Yet the answers are different:

$$|I(f)-Q(f)|\leq\frac{1}{24}$$
$$|I(g)-Q(g)|\leq\frac{5}{128}$$

It must be quite unlikely that there are two typos next to each other so I must have done something wrong. But what?

Comment: I believe you need to adjust your error formula; for Simpson's rule, $|E|\le\max|f^{(4)}(x)|\frac{(b-a)^5}{180n^4}$.

Comment: @user84413: this is the composite Simpson's rule. So in my case $n=1$.

Comment: If you're using $n=1$, so you're not partitioning the interval into smaller subintervals, you still need 180 in the denominator instead of 90(32).

Comment: @user84413: I thought [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Error) would apply.

Comment: I guess you are using $n=2$ in your estimate, since that's what this formula seems to indicate.  (It still doesn't seem to give the answers stated, though, as you say.)